Fill this partially-dotted Sudoku so that two sums are equal
Fill all 16 squares with a number so that every row, every column and every 2x2 box contains all the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 each exactly once.
Also the sum of the numbers in the six squares marked with a dot must be equal to the sum of the numbers in the ten squares that are NOT marked with a dot.



 The sum of all numbers is $40$, so the sum of the dotted numbers is $20$.


 We shall use the chess notation to refer to the numbers at the board cells.


 The sum $S$ of all dotted numbers but $c2$ is at most $16$, and this maximum is attained when $a1$ is $2$, and $a4$ and $d1$ are $1$'s.


 So $S=16$ and so $c2$ is $4$.


 Then $b1$ and $a3$ are $4$'s,


 and $a2$ and $c1$ are $3$'s.


 So $c4$ is $2$, $c3$ is $1$, $b2$ is $1$, $d2$ is $2$, $d3$ is $3$, $b3$ is $2$, $b4$ is $3$, and $d4$ is $4$:

 1324
 4213
 3142
 2431
 

